# Is there a built-in way for retrieving the parent object?

Tags: c#, .net, ormlite-servicestack

I have two (simplified) classes in ORMLite (using the SQLite provider, but shouldn't matter):

```
public class ParentClass
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index(Unique = true)]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public List<ChildClass> Children { get; set; }
} 

public class ChildClass
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index(Unique = true)]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

When I have a parent, I can simply do

```
var firstChild = parent.Children.First();
```

or similar to retrieve the child class directly. However when I need to do it the other way round, I need to do

```
var parent = db.Single<ParentClass>(new { Id = child.ParentId });
```

Is there a way to set up the data classes so I can simply do the following?

```
var parent = child.Parent;
```

An optimum solution would be one where the parent would only be retrieved from the database once (Note: I'm in a single-user environment and there is noone/nothing modifying my database externally).

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a property like:

```
[Reference]
public ParentClass Parent { get; set; }
```

on the `ChildClass`, and then you need to make sure that the property is properly filled up. You have the `ParentId` property on the child table in the database, so this shouldn't be any problem to fetch the parent by its ID - I suppose.